# How to find a particular 'string' in previous nodes, but within some range of previous nodes not in entire previous nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

How to find a particular 'string' in previous nodes, but within some range of previous nodes not in entire previous nodes.

For Example 1:
Input:
`<p>0Sum of [squares] test1<br/>[Factor1 Section]<b>A<br/>2Sum</b> of <i>(squares) test2 </i> test <br/>[Factor2] <b>(A)</b></p>`

Required Output:
If the the scenario is matched, I need to change the `<br/>` into `<p></p>`:
`<p>0Sum of [squares] test1</p><p>[Factor1 Section]<b>A<br/>2Sum</b> of <i>(squares) test2 </i> test <br/>[Factor2] <b>(A)</b></p>`

Example 2:
It should be work within the para not one para to another para. You can see the below example xml, in this case it don't make any changes.
Input:
`<p>[A]</b></p><p><br/>[0Sum of squares]</p>`

Required Output:
`<p>[A]</b></p><p><br/>[0Sum of squares]</p>`

in that first I need to find the `br[following-sibling::node()[1][matches(.,'^\[')]`, then need to find - If there is any "]" is present in previous nodes, but that finding range should be till the previous `<br/>` tag (i.e. one `<br/>` tag to previous `<br/>` tag).

Note: I have already make the code for that, here I have given below for your review. But I need better and straight forward code. Can some one help me out!

```
<xsl:template match="br[(following-sibling::node()[1][matches(normalize-space(.),'^\[')] and preceding-sibling::node()[matches(.,'\]')]>
<xsl:variable name="brcounts" select="count(preceding-sibling::br)"/>
<xsl:if test="$brcounts &gt; 0">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="(following-sibling::node()[1][matches(normalize-space(.),'^\[')] and preceding-sibling::node()[matches(.,'\]')]) and (preceding-sibling::node()[matches(.,'\]') and count(preceding-sibling::br) = $brcounts])">
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:copy />
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="$brcounts = 0">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="(following-sibling::node()[1][matches(normalize-space(.),'^\[')] and preceding-sibling::node()[matches(.,'\]')])">
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:copy />
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: what is expected output.

Comment: Hi Rupesh, now I have updated the required output. Kindly check and let me know in case of any clarification.

Comment: if you want output with other condition than you have to asked new question  rather than edit old answer accepted question. also can you describe what is difference between input and required output in Example 2. also your input in example 2 is invalid

Comment: I have given example 2 for don't do! in that we have test the conditions within in the para not between the para (i.e. condition is not required to work between sibling para's).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
<!-- Identical Transform -->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="br[following-sibling::node()[1][matches(., '^\[')]]
    [preceding-sibling::node()[matches(., '\]')]]
    [generate-id(.) = generate-id(preceding-sibling::node()[matches(., '\]')][1]/following::br[1])]">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/p>&lt;p></xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

**Output and Script**

[http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/pPgCcom/3](http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/pPgCcom)

Comment: Hi Ruspesh, It's working, but except the below scenario: In that one more condition required, that is it should be work within the para not one para to another para.  

INPUT:  
`<p>[A]</b></p>
<p><br/>[0Sum of squares]</p>`

Required OUTPUT:  
`<p>[A]</b></p>
<p><br/>[0Sum of squares]</p>`

Produced OUTPUT:(Incorrect)  
`<p>[A]</b></p>
<p></p><p>[0Sum of squares]</p>`  

Sorry, I didn't mentioned in my initial conversation!

Comment: Hi Rupesh, it is also not producing correct output:  

Input:  
`<p class=""><br/>[0Sum of squares] test1<br/>[Factor1 Section]<b>A<br/>2Sum</b> of <i>(squares) test2 </i> test <br/>[Factor2] <b>(A)</b></p>`  

Required Output:  
`<p><br/>[0Sum of squares] test1</p><p>[Factor1 Section]<b>A<br/>2Sum</b> of <i>(squares) test2 </i> test <br/>[Factor2] <b>(A)</b></p>`  

Produced Output:  
`<p><br/>[0Sum of squares] test1</p><p>[Factor1 Section]<b>A<br/>2Sum</b> of <i>(squares) test2 </i> test </p><p>[Factor2] <b>(A)</b></p>`

Comment: @PrabhuM, Answer is updated also you can check this [here](http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/pPgCcom/3)

Comment: Thanks, Rupesh. Now it's working fine! I will test with few examples and let you know in case of any.